# JsonResult not picking up ICollection in object when i post from ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js, jsonresult

I am using MVC 4 and have been struggling with getting Json from the client constructed by Knockout.Js back to my Controller Action. The Json gets posted ok and examining it in Fiddler all seems fine but when the JsonResults Action binds it the object produced doesn't have an ICollection that was present in the Json.

My Client ajax post looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: location.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.toJSON(this.Orders),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Message);
            }
        });
```

That produces the following Json:

```
[{"Number":1,"Properties":{"Id":2,"Title":"#333"},"UnitCost":"20"}]
```

My viewModel structure on the server side is so:

Order model

```
     public class VmOrder 

{

    public int Number
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ICollection<VmProperty> Properties
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal UnitCost
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

 }
```

Property model

```
   public class VmProperty
    {

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
```

And lastly my Controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Order(ICollection<VmOrder> Orders)
    {

        // further server-side validation, save to database, etc
        return Json("Saved", "");
    }
```

Although i get the Number and UnitCost the Properties collection is null, any ideas?

Comment: `"Properties":{"Id":2,"Title":"#333"}` contains just an object and not an array. The array version would look like: `"Properties":[{"Id":2,"Title":"#333"}]`. So on the C# side you need `public VmProperty Properties
    {
        get;
        set;
    }` instead of the collection.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I had set the Property model as and observableArray in Knockout but for some reason it didn't pass the JSON as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nemsev said, "Properties":{"Id":2,"Title":"#333"} contains just an object and not an array. The array version would look like: "Properties":[{"Id":2,"Title":"#333"}]. So on the C# side you need public VmProperty Properties { get; set; } instead of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8"
```

with:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

You were missing a `;` and thus resulting in an invalid and non-existent `Content-Type` request header.

Comment: Thanks, i made that change but that wasnt the issue, it actually made no difference.

Comment: Well actually this makes a difference. After you fixed your actual bug (the format of the JSON array) you should also make sure that the Content-Type header is properly set, otherwise the model binder won't bind your model.

Comment: honest, it really didn't make any difference